# Find the closest point and the distance from vector v to the subspace spanned by the vectors a, b and c

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

$$ v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ -2\end{pmatrix} $$
$$ a = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} $$
$$ b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ c = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

according to my textbook, I can find the closest point by using these formulas below

(x is equal to the closest point and A is equal to the matrix that has the vectors a,b and c in it)

**x = A * r**

r = k^-1 * f

k = A^T * A

f = A^T * v

I found the matrix K, which is written below

$$ k = \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 4 & -2 \\ 4 & 6 & -8 \\ -2  & -8 & 14\end{pmatrix}$$

however, the k matrix does not have an inverse because its determinant is zero, so because it has no inverse, i can't find the closest point x.

Im not sure what else i can do here, is there no point that is close enough to the vector v? or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: v,a,b,c all live in $\mathbb R^4$, k is in $\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$, you are talking of apples and pears.

Comment: Yes you are right, but my textbook had another example where v,a,b,c were in R^3 and k was in R^(2x2) i don't think the dimensions matter in this type of problem

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. Are you mixing up two or more different questions?

Comment: The fact that $k$ is singular means that the three vectors aren’t linearly independent. Discard one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance minimizer of $v$ to the subspace $W = \operatorname{span}\,\{a, b, c\}$ is precisely the orthogonal projection of $v$ to $W$. Let's find it.

First notice that $c = a - 2b$ so the subspace $W$ is spanned by $\{a,b\}$. Now use the Gram-Schmidt process on $\{a, b\}$ to obtain an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$ for $W$.

$$e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$e_2 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 4 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}
$$

The orthogonal projection of $v$ to $W$ is given by:

$$Pv = \langle v, e_1\rangle e_1 + \langle v, e_2\rangle e_2 = \frac12 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

The distance from $v$ to $W$ is precisely the distance from $v$ to $Pv$ since it is the minimizer:

$$\|v - Pv\|_2 = \frac12\left\|\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 3 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}\right\|_2 = 3$$

Comment: so just to clarify, the closest point is 1/2(1,1,1,1) ? and the distance to that point is 3?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master Yes. You should verify the calculations, just in case.